# VB.net - show ALL data from database

Tags: database, vb.net

I have this code that I would like to show all data from database on the click of my update button, but right now it's only showing the last row.
I thought the While would repeat itself and post every row, but.. yeah..
Thanks.

```
Private Sub update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles update.Click
Dim show_rows As String
Dim Conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\...\mydb.mdb")
Conn.Open()
Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM dreamware_db", Conn)
Dim read As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
If read.HasRows Then
While read.Read()
show_rows = read.Item("text")
post_dreams.Text = "Show:" & show_rows
End While
End If
Conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not bind a databound control instead of building a string?

Answer (score 1):

It's only showing the last row because you reset the value of `show_rows` each time through the loop.

You could do something like this:

```
show_rows = show_rows & read.Item("text") & vbCrLf
```

Comment: That makes sense.. How do I come around this? Can I use some += of some kind?

Edit:
That worked, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great...if my answer helped, how about an upvote and accept it?

Comment: Strings are immutable, so `StringBuilder` is really a better solution than concatenating a string repeatedly within a loop.

Comment: Maybe...if it's a small number of records, concatenating the strings is not a big deal. If the number is large and performance is poor, then StringBuilder is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder` class instead:

```
Private Sub update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles update.Click
    Dim show_rows As New StringBuilder()
    Dim Conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\...\mydb.mdb")
    Conn.Open()
    Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM dreamware_db", Conn)
    Dim read As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

    If read.HasRows Then
        While read.Read()
            show_rows.AppendLine(read.Item("text"))
        End While
    End If
    Conn.Close()

    ' Do something with show_rows here
    post_dreams.Text = "Show:" & show_rows.ToString()
End Sub
```